# picamera.mmal error occuring during running the picamera

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

[I was trying to aquire video using Raspberry pi and this was an error that occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElFsd.jpg)

I was trying to aquire video using Raspberry pi and this was an error that occured

Comment: Please do the [tour], and read about [ask] and [mcve] then [edit] your question. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.